# Copy constructor, constness and rvalues

Tags: c++, constants

I'm currently learning about move/copy constructors, constness and rvalues.

"Older literature" about C++ says:

> "A copy constructor must take a const argument since it should be able to take temporaries/rvalues which are not modifiable"

But nowadays, with C++ 11's move constructors, we can directly handle rvalues. This brings me to the conclusion, that it's no longer mandatory to make a copy constructor take a const reference.

Is this true? (I could neither confirm nor falsify the statement with currently existing literature and community articles.) A short discussion about the pro and contras of having the copy constructor const would also be appreciated.

Comment: I am not a C++ developer but I htink that your copy constructor should not modify the original object. Hence, having it const seems a good idea.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: That's for sure in most cases. But understanding the "why" behind such questions greatly helps to build up good knowledge in the language. And MAYBE you will run into a case where modifying the original would actually be an option, for example when you want to count how often an object was copied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not true. You want your copy constructor to take a `const T&` and your move constructor to take a `T&&`. Why? Well think about what happens if we pass a `const` rvalue. It can't bind to the `T&&`, because it's not `const`. It can, however, bind to the `const T&`, which is able to bind to anything. If it were just a `T&` instead, it wouldn't be able to, and we'd never be able to copy from `const` rvalues.

To think about it in another way: the only time a move constructor is useful is if we have an rvalue (likely a temporary object) that we can steal from, which means that it must be non-`const`. All the other cases must invoke the copy constructor instead. The only reference type that will bind to everything else is a `const` lvalue reference.